# How do I send a webhook to discord using google assistant IFTTT

Tags: discord, webhooks, ifttt, google-assistant

I have recently been trying to get google home to send a **webhook** to discord using the **IFTTT**
integration with **webhooks** and **google assistant**

I have the ***"Say a phrase with text ingredient"*** Google assistant option.

My **webhook** Body section is filled in with:

```
    {
    "content": " {{TextField}}"
    }
```

And the **webhook** link is perfect too.

But when I tell my **google assistant** to run the **applet** it does nothing

Does anyone know how to do fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like sending a message from Google Assistant to Discord, because I made an applet like that, I used the same phrase with text ingredient option but I didn't use a webhook, instead I used the Discord service and then set it to post a message in a channel, then typed this code as the message: `{{TextField}}<br> <br>`